# Is my system too complicated for Solve?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of three nonlinear equations using *Mathematica*. `Solve` takes forever to run and never solves my system of equations. Is my system too complicated?

I have looked through the suggestions on using `Solve` in the *Mathematica* help, but none of these seem to work. I am wondering if I am going about solving the problem the wrong way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have attached my code below.

#### Solving the Tensegrity Model

Defining reference conditions

```
l0 = Sqrt[0.375];
s0 = 0.5 ;
k = 1;
```

Using prestress to define

```
ξ = 1 - lR/l0;

lR[ξval_] := l0 (1 - ξval);

lRvalues = Table[lR[ξrange], {ξrange, {0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0}}];
```

Defining cable lengths

```
Clear[sx, sy, sz]
l1[sx_] := 0.5 Sqrt[sx^2 + sy^2 - 2 sy + 2];
l2 := 0.5 Sqrt[sy^2 + sz^2 - 2 sz + 2];
l3[sx_] := 0.5 Sqrt[sz^2 + sx^2 - 2 sx + 2];

F1[lR_] = k (l1[sx] - lR);
F2[lR_] = k (l2 - lR);
F3[lR_] = k (l3[sx] - lR);

F1values = Table[F1[lr], {lr, lRvalues}];
F2values = Table[F2[lr], {lr, lRvalues}];
F3values = Table[F3[lr], {lr, lRvalues}];
F1values[[1]] /. sx -> 0.5
(*-0.612372 + 0.5 Sqrt[2.25 - 2 sy + sy^2]*)

sxval = Range[0.5, 2, 0.5];
For[j = 1, j < Length[sxval] + 1, j++,
 For[i = 1, i < Length[F1values] + 1, i++,
  Solve[{(F1values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) (1 - sy)/l1[sxval[[j]]] == 
     F2values[[i]] sy/l2, 
    F2values[[i]] (1 - sz)/l2 == (F3values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) sz/
      l3[sxval[[j]]], 
    T == 2 ((F1values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) sxval[[j]]/
         l1[sxval[[j]]] + (F3values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) (
         sxval[[j]] - 1)/l3[sxval[[j]]])}, {T, sy, sz}]
  (*sy1 = NSolve[(F1values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) (1 - sy)/l1[sxval[[j]]] ==
  F2values[[i]] sy/l2, sy, Reals] // FullSimplify;*)
  (*Print[sy1]*)
  ]
 ]`
```

Comment: You haven't replaced all values of sx in your expression inside the loop. Is this correct? If you do this and also change solve to FindRoot (starting with sensible values) it solves it very quickly.

Comment: All the values of sx should be gone in the solve function (I recently edited the post so that's the case at least)...

Comment: sx still appears in the function as far as I can tell, both in the first and second elements of the list.

Comment: I changed the definitions of F2values and F3 values (updated in the above post), and I think that removed all of the sx values from the solve function. I did FullSimplify of the individual terms and all sx terms were gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Solve`, I recommend `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[{
  (F1values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) (1 - sy)/l1[sxval[[j]]] == F2values[[i]] sy/l2, 
  F2values[[i]] (1 - sz)/l2 == (F3values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) sz/l3[sxval[[j]]], 
  T == 2 ((F1values[[i]] /. sx -> sxval[[j]]) sxval[[j]]/l1[sxval[[j]]] + (F3values[[i]] /. 
         sx -> sxval[[j]]) (sxval[[j]] - 1)/l3[sxval[[j]]])
  },
  {{T, 0}, {sy, 0}, {sz, 0}}]
```

That should work. In the current loop, it won't print anything, so you will have to include a `Print` statement or similar to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I used FindRoot like you suggested and that worked much better. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Be careful that there is only a single solution as Findroot will, in general find the solution close to the starting values that you set. If you are looking at a system with multiple solutions then you will miss some with this method.

Comment: Sounds good! I have some graphs to compare my results too so I will look into that...

Comment: @AlC what kind of tensegrity problem are you trying to solve?